# CSS/HTML: Buttons with PayPal Shopping Cart

Tags: html, css

PayPal requires you to use one of their buttons or one you have created as an image in their shopping cart.

How can I work around this and use CSS/HTML button? Button is defined as a class, with size & color.

Here is the code from PayPal using my button image not using CSS/HTML.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="93BSEETFTS1PN">
<input type="image" src="http://www.yoursitename.com/images/addtocartbutton.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to format the code correctly in your post so that we can see it

Answer (score 0):

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="93BSEETFTS1PN">

<input class="CUSTOM" type="image" src="http://www.yoursitename.com/images/addtocartbutton.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

CSS

```
#CUSTOM {background-image:url('...') !important;}
```